# YouTube button for the website

Tags: button, youtube, youtube-api, subscribe

I went to https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button#Configuration_Options to create YouTube Subscribe button, but for some reason instead of buttons I could choose from I see gray boxes and there is no code shown. Please help

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The basic code, test it on your web page :

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>

<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="GoogleDevelopers" data-layout="default" data-count="default"></div>
```